# Resume Crawling on big sites in PHPCrawl

Tags: php, session

Is there any way to save session of crawler in mysql database or in any way and resume this session using PHP? http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no build-in way to do that, but yes, you can add session management on your own by extending the existing classes.

Comment: @SeekPhp: I'm sorry I don't know a crawler class in PHP that supports resuming. But there is other software that does this, like http://www.httrack.com/ which also has a commandline interface you can easily call from your PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

since version 0.81 phpcrawl is able to resume crawling processes
(http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/resume_aborted_processes.html)